# Can you find by three attributes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Is this type of thing allowed in Rails: `Model.find_by_X_and_Y_and_Z(attribute1, attribute2, attribute3)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From http://ar.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html

> It‘s also possible to use multiple
>   attributes in the same find by
>   separating them with "and", so you get
>   finders like
>   Person.find_by_user_name_and_password
>   **or even
>   Payment.find_by_purchaser_and_state_and_country**.
>   So instead of writing
>   Person.find(:first, :conditions =>
>   ["user_name = ? AND password = ?",
>   user_name, password]), you just do
>   Person.find_by_user_name_and_password(user_name,
>   password).

Answer (score 0):

As another solution I think you could try combining several scopes.I mean you probably will use some separated scopes to retrieve some data anyway,so you might as well just give it a try.

So,imagine you have a model:

```
class YourModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :sent,where(:sent => true}
  scope :by_param,lambda{|query| where("param= ?","#{query}")}
end
```

then just use

```
YourModel.sent.by_par("something")
```